# How can I implement projects and tasks with DDD

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, symfony

I have two entities: Projects and Task. I can implements this object as Value Object but I wonder about the  whether that is good approach? Task might change own title or status and VO should be immutable. How implements this object?

I wonder  about the in Project entity I should add addTask method or I should add Tasks via TaskController?  Whether TaskController is necessary when Project entity has addTask method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this documentation on Doctrine Associations / Relations:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html

It should explain what you need to do.

Essentially, your Project Entity should have an `addTask()` method where you add the task. Your Project will have an ArrayCollection of Tasks. Then you can use you `getTask()` method (you create this) to get the Task (if you need it).

The documentation gives good examples, so take a at that first.

**EDIT #2** Based on comments.

So, it's seems you don't understand the article very well. You would have separate methods in each of your Entities to do what you need that is related to that particular Entity. I'm not certain what methods you actually want.

So for example, you gave in the comments two type of methods: changeTask and changeNameTask.

In you code, you could do something like this:

```
$project = new Project();
$task1 = new Task();
$task1->setName("My Task Name");
... // Do other things with task1

$project->addTask($task1);

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($project); // Save to db.
$em->persist($task1);
$em->flush();

// Now let's add a new Task (different name).
$task2 = new Task();
$task2->setName("Another Task");
...

$project->addTask($task2);

// Remove the old Task...
$em->remove($task1);
$em->persist($project); // Save to db.
$em->persist($task2);
$em->flush();

// You can also get the Task if you need it.
$task2 = $project->getTask();   // Presumes that this is an object not an array.
```

The above should make sense...

Comment: Okej, but whether TaskController ? Whether in Project Entity add method changeTask or changeNameTask?  It is necessary?

Comment: I would use Value Object's, but I wonder  when I get record via Doctrine(object has not setters) how change  name object ?

Comment: Hi there Matrix12. I edited my post based on feedback in your comments.

Comment: Thanks you for answers. Have nice day !

Comment: I have a question. I have few bundle's and I wonder how implement structure directories. I thought that create directory, applications, infrastructure, presentation, domain. Whether I should  place entities UserBundle,ProjectBundle to Domain but they Controller's on Presentation ? Or not create each bundle only place all entities to Domain directory?

Comment: Hi there @Matrix12 . Can you please post this as a separate question and not as a comment here. Include as much information in the question as you have. If you post as a new question, you are more likely to get more/better responses. Thank you!